# Windows 11 default taskbar pinned apps?

Tags: windows-registry, taskbar, regedit

TLDR: I want to reset the taskbar pinned apps to the default (similar to the first login of a new user)

I found taskband in regedit but this value isn't in the default user's registry hive. It seems that the taskbar pinned apps is generated instead of fixed.

As the target computer is running Windows 11 Home, there is no Group Policy editor and we need to use regedit. So how to trigger the generation process, and ultimately, reset the taskbar pinned apps to default?